# What part of the website from Django/ Python to change to get a pre-written text in search bar?

Tags: python, css, django, html

I have the .css which hard codes the place of the search bar. The search bar is using a variable, keywords, called in the forms.py. Lastly the view.py might be another possibility to get the pre-populated text of "Search for a tool" in the search bar.

Which of these codes can I set the value= "Search for a tool", like I do in the HTML editor in the browser?

**style.css** File probably is the most confusing for me because I can change the initial definitions to [type = "text", value = "Search for a tool"], and then the search bar moves to a new location on the html page and does not have the pre=written text.

```
...

.search{
    width:350px;
    margin-left:120px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height:75px;


}
.search input[type="text"], .search input[type='number'], .search input[type="password"] {
    margin:20px;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding: 4px; background:#d8f6fd;
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid #66c8de;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.search input[type="submit"]{
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    float:right;
}
...
```

The **forms.py**. This uses a char field. I get many errors when I try to add parameters in CharField( blank = False, default = "Enter a tool name")
I am guessing there is nothing that would initialize the search bar with this .py

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    keywords = forms.CharField()
```

THe **views.py** Seems like it will only process a request from the search bar, and I would assume that it could initialize.

```
def search(request):
    template = loader.get_template('sharesystem/search.html')
    form = Search()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Search(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            keywords = form.cleaned_data['keywords']
            tools = Tool.objects.filter(name__contains = keywords).values()
            if (keywords is ''):
                tools = Tool.objects.all()
            context = RequestContext(request, {
            'tools' : tools, 'form':form })
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
    tools = Tool.objects.all()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
            'form' : form,'tools' : tools})

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

To follow up **base.html** When i add a new line for input, I get mutiple search boxes. When class='search' is called, what do I put in that div?

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
            <div class="centerframe">
            <div id="logo">
                <a  href="{% url 'sharesystem:index' %}" ><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}sharesystem/images/logo.png"border="none" ></a>
            </div>

            <div class='search' >
            <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter a tool name"/>

            <form action="/sharesystem/search/" method="GET" style='margin-bottom:0;'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
                    {{ search_form.keywords }}
                    </form>

            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:24px;">
            <form action="/sharesystem/search/" method="GET" style='margin-bottom:0;'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" value="View All Tools"  />

            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your business needs, and what browsers you need to support, I'd like to recommend using the HTML input 'placeholder' attribute.

You would need to either override your forms init function and update the widget attrs dictionary from there or explicitly set the widget in your CharField declaration.

keywords = forms.CharField(                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search for a tool'}))

Comment: That removed the search box in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `placeholder` attribute of the `input` HTML tag:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter a tool name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take  a loo into [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) data for Forms.

```
form = Form(initial={'value': 'My Search!'})
```

In your case:
    form = Search()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Search(request.GET, initial={'value': 'My Search!'})

Comment: what is a loo and where it initial data for Forms? I recognize __init__.

Comment: @JoeWaldroncheck my update. when you create a form instance in your view try to pass there initial param.

Comment: THe initialization is in `form = Search()`. I can change that to `form = Search(initial={'value': 'My Search!'}` or have the lines look like `form = Search()
 form = Form(initial={'value': 'My Search!'})`

Comment: Yes, you can try it. Form(initial={'value': 'My Search!'}) will be enough.

Comment: I tried and I get the error `Exception Value:  

name 'Form' is not defined` I saw some progress with `<input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter a tool name">` but it made a duplicate search bar.

Comment: It should be in your views.py. form = Form(initial={'value': 'My Search!'}).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @wolendranh. I don't see it in my views.py I only see the code listed about and some import from in the header.

Comment: I also see that some people use that in forms.py In my condition statement for def Search(request) could you please tell me where that would go?